# Authorize attribute with role redirects to Access denied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization

I have simple ASP .NET MVC application.
I'm trying to do authentication and authorization.

For authentication I have setup Azure AD and I'm adding role to the `HttpContext.User` using a middleware.
I know that the role is added because on the View if I do conditional rendering with `User.IsInRole("Admin")` the UI is correctly rendered. But the controller with Authorize[Roles = "Admin"] redirects me to

> http://localhost:5433/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FAdd

I even tired `Authorize[Policy = "Admin"]` but the result is same.

From services if I remove `AddMicrosoftIdentityUI()` then it is redirected to

> http://localhost:5433/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FAdd

I don't know how does the Authorize attributes work. Does it not check `User.IsInRole("Admin")`?  Please let me know

Also for me the roles are added in UserDetails table and I do have a role as 'Admin'

Also I could have written a custom attribute and make it work. I just want to know what is the real issue right now.

Code:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContextPool<EmpDBContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")));

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");


            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                 .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
                options.AddPolicy("Employee", policy => policy.RequireRole("Employee"));
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseAddClaimsFromDb(); // CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE TO ADD ROLE TO USER

            // CHECKING IF ROLE WAS ADDED
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.User != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    bool x = context.User.IsInRole("Admin");
                    System.Console.WriteLine(x); // RETURNS TRUE

                }
                await next();
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

**UseAddClaimsFromDb (AddClaimMiddleware.cs)**

```cs
public class AddClaimMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public AddClaimMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, EmpDBContext dBContext)
        {
            var user = httpContext.User;

            // does not perist between request
            if(user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string email = user.Identity.Name;

                UserDetail userDetail = await dBContext.UserDetails.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.EmailId == email);
                string role = userDetail?.Role ?? "Employee";

                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));

                user.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

               // httpContext.Session.SetString("employeeId", userDetail.EmployeeId.ToString());

            }

            await next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the above by rearranging the middleware sequence

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAddClaimsFromDb();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I still don't know the real reason why it worked. It would be great if someone can update this or add a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar approach but I'm using Blazor WASM with Azure AD B2C.

In order to add the roles claims to the identity of the current user you need to *overwrite* the existing identity (ClaimPrincipal) in order to have a single *identity* with the roles required.

I use this code:

```
context.Principal = await claimsTransformation.TransformAsync(context.Principal);
...
 public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            // Clone current identity
            var clone = principal.Clone();
            var newIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;

            // Support AD and local accounts
            var nameId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier ||
                                                              c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (nameId == null)
            {
                return principal;
            }

            // Get user from database
            var userResponse = await _userService.GetAsync(nameId.Value);
            if (!userResponse.Succeeded || userResponse.Data is null)
            {
                return principal;
            }

            var user = userResponse.Data;
            var rolesResponse = await _userService.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

            if (rolesResponse.Succeeded && rolesResponse.Data is not null)
            {
                // Add role claims to cloned identity
                foreach (var role in rolesResponse.Data.UserRoles.Where(w => w.Selected).ToList())
                {
                    var claim = new Claim(newIdentity.RoleClaimType, role.RoleName);
                    newIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
                }
            }

            return clone;
        }
```

I apply this transformation in my Toekn Validation, but in your case I think should be injected in the middleware part.

Comment: when you say `context.Principal`  which context are you rereferring to?

Comment: From you're point of view is the `user` var

Comment: So what you suggest is that I assign httpContext.user to a new user rather than adding claims to the current httpContext.user

Comment: Yes, you cannot add claims to an existing ClaimPrincipal, you need to override the original.

Comment: `var user = httpContext.User.Clone(); if(user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
   ...  httpContext.User = user;  }`
But still the same